# Type 'Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Course>'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I have a Angular 8 application and using firebase.  I want to retrive data from a service. So I made a function for retrieving the data. But I get an error on that function

I googled a lot and read the firebase documentation. But it didnt fixed the problem.

So this is the function I have:

```
 findCourseByUrl(courseUrl: string): Observable<Course> {

    return this.db.list('courses', ref => {
      return ref.orderByChild('url').equalTo(courseUrl);
    }).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(data => data[0]));

  }
```

But I still get this error:

```
Type 'Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Course>'.
  Type 'AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Course': id, url
```

If I do this:

```
  findCourseByUrl(courseUrl: string): Observable<Course> {

    return this.db.list('courses', ref => {
      return ref.orderByChild('url').equalTo(courseUrl);
    }).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Course;
            return { ...data };
          });
        }));

  }
```

I will then get this error:

```
Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>'.
  Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<unknown>'.ts(2339)
```

```
Type 'Observable<{ id: string; url: string; description: string; iconUrl: string; courseListIcon: string; longDescription: string; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Course>'.
  Type '{ id: string; url: string; description: string; iconUrl: string; courseListIcon: string; longDescription: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Course': id, url, description, iconUrl, and 2 more.ts(2322)
```

This is the model:

```
export interface Course {
    id: string;
    url: string;
    description: string;
    iconUrl: string;
    courseListIcon: string;
    longDescription: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your code like this:

```
findCourseByUrl(courseUrl: string): Observable<Course> {

    return this.db.object('courses', ref => {
      return ref.equalTo(courseUrl);
    }).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.val() as Course;
            const id = a.payload.key;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
        }));
  }
```

**EDIT**

The code above is a mixture for single objects and list of objects, so it's not working. The following code is for a single object to get.

```
findCourseByUrl(courseUrl: string): Observable<Course> {

    return this.db.object(`courses/${courseUrl}`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.val() as Course;
          const id = a.payload.key;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
  }
```

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I edited my answer try this. If it don't work please provide your model of `Course`.

Comment: Type 'Observable<{ id: string; url: string; description: string; iconUrl: string; courseListIcon: string; longDescription: string; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Course>'.
  Type '{ id: string; url: string; description: string; iconUrl: string; courseListIcon: string; longDescription: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Course': id, url, description, iconUrl, and 2 more.ts(2322)

Comment: I edited my answer but not really sure if its the right way to get a single node from the realtime database.

Comment: Thank you. But still get this errors: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554). Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)